# Store data is not loading ,when using proxy, but it is working fine with static

Tags: extjs

Store data is not loading ,when using proxy, but it is working fine with static.
 means when I put hard codded data in my store , then it working fine.
my code is like blow...

model

```
Ext.define('new_app.model.BlogModel', {
  extend : 'Ext.data.Model',
  config : {
    fields: [{
        name: "firstName",
        type: "string"
    },{
        name:"lastName",
        type:"string"
    }]
  }
});
```

Store

```
Ext.define('new_app.store.blogs',{
  extend:'Ext.data.Store',
  config:{
    model: "new_app.model.BlogModel",
      proxy: {
          type: 'ajax',
          url: "data/testStore.js", 
        reader: {
          type: 'json',
          rootProperty: 'data'
        }
      },
      autoLoad: true
    }
 });
```

And my view

```
 Ext.define('new_app.view.Blog',{
  extend:'Ext.navigation.View',
   xtype:'blog',

requires:[
    "Ext.dataview.List"

],
config: {
    title:'Blog',
    iconCls:'star',

    items:[{
        xtype:'list',
        itemTpl: '<div class="contact">{firstName} <strong>{lastName}</strong></div>',
        title:'Recent Posts',
        store:'blogs'

     }]

},


initialize: function(){
    this.callParent();
    // var storeData = Ext.widget('myblogs');
    // console.log(storeData);
    // this.setData(storeData);
}
```

});

Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

It all looks good except that proxy/reader should be preferably configured on model, not on store. Now, how to debugg the thing:

1. Verify that there a request sent to the server (store is autoLoad so it should)
2. Verify that a valid json comes back
3. See if rootProperty matches that what comes in json

BTW, this looks like Sencha Touch, right?